# Integrated volatility and realized volatility

Tags: volatility

Since integrated variance can be estimated via the sum of squared returns (which connects closly to the realized volatility, can I also asusme that "the integrated volatility is an estimator of the realized volatility?" Thank you.

Comment: I think it's the other way around: realised variance (= sum of squared returns) estimates integrated variance, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realized_variance#Properties_under_ideal_conditions). Of course, there are many noise and jump corrections.